# Mathematica defines a function as list

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction

This might be a very silly question but i'm defining a function as:

```
\[Chi][AR_] := ((AR^(2) - 1)/(AR^(2) + 1));
```

which is clearly a scalar function of AR; however when I do:

```
Dimensions[\[Chi][AR]]
```

It tells me this is a vector of two elements. Inded i tried to check what those elements where and i got:

```
In[21]:= \[Chi][AR][[2]]

Out[21]= 1/(1 + AR^2)
```

while the first element is:

```
In[22]:= \[Chi][AR][[1]]

Out[22]= -1 + AR^2
```

this is really annoying, anybody does why it's happening?
(Maybe it's a silly question the solution is obvious but i'm too much asleep to notice it...)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dimensions>>Generalizations and Extensions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dimensions.html) says:

> *Dimensions works with any head,not just List.*

So,

```
Dimensions[foo[x,y]]
(* {2} *)
```

and

```
foo[[1]]
(* x *)

foo[[2]]
(* y *)
```

In your case, checking the `FullForm` of `χ[z]`

```
FullForm[χ[z]]
```

gives

```
Times[Plus[-1,Power[z,2]],Power[Plus[1,Power[z,2]],-1]]
```

Thus,

```
χ[z][[0]]
(* Times *)

χ[z][[1]]
(* -1 + z^2 *)

χ[z][[2]]
(* 1/(1 + z^2) *)
```

Comment: So it's basically applying dimensiona to times[...]? Also if I define two vectorial functions, can i define the function given by their cross product by just doing Cross[f1[x],f2[x] ]?

Comment: @user3810266, re "applying dimensions to Times", yes; and re "Also, if...", I think so.